# Getting error " 'getAttribute' of undefined " for the last element in the loop

Tags: javascript, html, loops

Can not understand why I'm get an error for the last element in the loop? I see other questions on SOF, but I does not found an answer for my case.

I'm trying to get the list of **tag a** elemnents, but

```
<script>

    let a = document.body.getElementsByTagName('a');

    function getList(list) {

        let ii;
        for (let i = 0; i , a.length; i++) {

            if (a[i].getAttribute('href')) {
                ii = a[i].getAttribute('href');
                console.log(ii); // get the list of elements that contains attr "href". 
                                 // and an Error for the last element -
                                 // error 'getAttribute' of undefined.
            }
        }

        return ii;
    }

    getList(); // start for test

</script>


<body>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="http://google.com">http://google.com</a></li>
      <li><a href="/tutorial">/tutorial.html</a></li>
      <li><a href="local/path">local/path</a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: `for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put condition `<`;

```
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
```

Comment: oh... automistake... I drink too many coffee :).

Thank you buddy!

Answer (score 1):

You need to fix this

```
 for (let i = 0; i , a.length; i++)
```

to `for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++)`

it is giving error as the index is out of bound